# Flutter how to remove default padding from stack positioned

Tags: flutter

CODE:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Container(
              width: Get.width,
              height: Get.width * 16 / 9,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(top: 16, left: 16, child: BackButton()),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.delete_forever,
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        size: 32,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

There is some margin on IconButton.

I think IconButton should be tight on bottom left.

How to remove margin IconButton and screen side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's the default padding of the Icon Button only...
That is, the stack is placing the button at bottom left but icon in the button is padded by default.

You can try using Gesture detector with that icon as a child...
You will get different result...
Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: thanks, so.. would you give me some hint to solve it?

Comment: Already gave you right... Just use GestrueDetector instead on IconButton, with the required icon as a child to the GestureDectector...